# How to tell angular cli to stop using minified version of a vendor js file?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I have a build that includes the following scripts in my angular.json file:

```
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/lodash/index.js",
          "node_modules/backbone/backbone.js",
          "node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js"
        ]
```

As you can see there, I'm including `node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js`, which is the non-minified version of the jointjs library.

However, when I run `ng serve` it continues to bundle the `joint.min.js` file, which resides in the same directory as `join.js`.

I would like to use the non-minified version while in dev, to help me track issues with params I'm passing to the library.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds obvious, but have you flushed your cache?  I'm trying to find a way to set serving logs to be verbose so that you can tell which (and maybe why) it is serving a particular script.  Actually, use `ng server --verbose` and see if it provides any insight on what it is serving.

Comment: It's serving the vendor.js flle normally, which contains all vendor files concatenated. But for some reason. joint.min.js is concatenated there instead of join.js as I was expecting. For a prod build that'd be fine, but for a dev build I'd like the non-minified version.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can redirect to the correct file in the `tsconfig.json` file like this.

```
"paths": {
        "jointjs": [
        "node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js"
      ]
    }
```

Also I don't think you really need to have anything at all in scripts. What you put here gets included in another output file `scripts.js` which is separate from `vendor.js` and is meant if you want to include some scripts like the includes in a webpage. In this case all the related libraries get included by `joint.js` automatically and go into `vendor.js` so there is no need to include them again. Here is the documentation about [global scripts in angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts).

Another option is that you edit the package.json file in the jointjs npm module (npm_modules/jointjs/package.json) directly and change the entry `"main": "./dist/joint.min.js",` to  `"main": "./dist/joint.js",`. This is a bit of a hack since you are changing the npm package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I use this I get an error building, though: `error TS2665: Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'jointjs' resolves to an untyped module at 'C:/.../node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js', which cannot be augmented.`

Comment: How do you import it in TypeScript code? I have used `import * as joint from 'jointjs';` and it works.

Comment: That's how I import as well. It works if I don't use the path config, but if I add that setting, I get the error when building.

Comment: Yes with the path the typing's stop working but for me it compiles ok and the non minified code is included in the vendor.js. I have updated the answer with another option you can try that.

Comment: Thanks again @AlesD, I did get going by manually changing JointJs's package, but this is not a sustainable solution - this is a very common problem. I hope there is another way to get the non-minified file there during development.